# Develop Raspberry apps from windows

Tags: python, windows, git, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to open files from a Raspberry pi in windows for editing (using for example notepad++)?

I am currently using the built in python IDE in Raspbian but i feel that it would speed up the development process if i could use a windows IDE for development. I have also tried using a git repo to share files between the PI and Windows but it is a bit cumbersome to.

Or does anyone have any other ideas about workflow between Windows and Raspberry?

Comment: If you're just editing Python files, then sure you can. You could network share a folder on the Pi or in Windows and edit/run the files from the networked location.

Comment: I'm mostly editing python, html and java script-files. Is it something like this? http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/share-your-raspberry-pis-files-and-folders-across-a-network.html

Comment: Yep, just like that. You may also find it useful to use a program like PuTTY to SSH into the RPi and run the files _on_ the RPi but from your PC. That way your RPi doesn't need a keyboard, monitor, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a SAMBA server on your Raspberry Pi, set your python project folder as a network disk. Then you can use any windows IDE you like, just open the file which is on the network disk.

Currently I am using VS2015 + Python Tools for Visual Studio for remote debugging purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. I go through many ways and I found one of the best way is using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php).

It's very easy for you to edit and update file with notepad++ right in the Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set up a VM on your windows machine with rasbian running? Something like this will get you started: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/emulate-raspberry-pi-pc/

Otherwise - set up a network share between the two, edit files on your windows computer, & run from the pi.